# call fragment method but fragment not prepared complitily

Tags: android, fragment

I want to dynamically create fragment. So when click the navigation fragment item, it will trigger the callback function in the activity to communicate with detail fragment. Here is the callback faction in activity:

```
public void getChatRoomId(long chatroom_id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    MsgChatRoom msgChatRoom = new MsgChatRoom();

    ft.replace(R.id.activity_chat_MsgChatroom_container, msgChatRoom, "messages");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    msgChatRoom.startQuery(chatroom_id);
}
```

I could call the startQuery method, but in that method I need some arguments should be initialize in `onCreateActivity()`. However, at the time when I call `startQuery`, the Fragment does not have called `OncreateActivity`. So there will be a error:

> .... on a null object reference

How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using setArguments?

Comment: @Pooya thanks. setArguments make it works

Comment: great! just added the answer for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the fragment by using Fragment's `setArguments(Bundle)` function.

When you create the fragment pass your arguments by `setArguments()` and then in your fragment retrieve them by calling `getArguments()` in this way you don't wait for specific fragment's life-cycle to be able to use your data.

For more information you can visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html which also contains couple of examples of using these functions